# Getting only the image with certain #tag instagram

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USERID/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&count=5");
$data = json_decode($json);
$tag = 'alle';

$images = array();
foreach( $data->data as $user_data ) {
    $images[] = (array) $user_data->images->standard_resolution->url;
}
$someJSON = json_encode($images);
  echo $someJSON;
?>
```

Here i get what i want, the latest 5 pictures from my private instagram. However i want to sort these pictures by tag. My question is how to do that. I only want the image with the tag called #alle

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $json = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USERID/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&count=5");
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $tag = 'alle';
    $all_tags = $data['tags'];

    $images = array();
    foreach ($data as $data_key => $data_value) {
        foreach ($data['tags'] as $tag_key => $tag_value) {
            if( $tag_value == '#' . $tag) {
                $images[$data_key] = $data_value;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

You have to compare the json tag keys and add the picture to the new array if 1 of the tags equels the desired tag.

EDIT (you have to do some work yourself, I already provided an example):

you print out the array you get from `json_decode($json, TRUE);` by using `var_dump($data);` when you know the tags check for the desired one(s) and add these pictures to your new array you created with  `$images = array();`. Just debug every value until you understand how to write foreach loops and if comparisons and how you can use them in this situation.

Comment: sorry i dont understand how to integrate with other script, cant make it work (php newbie)

Comment: @KJKIT I added some information that hopefully helps you on your way